# Htaccess directory with parameter to url parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I have a url domain/p1/p2/p3/?order=p4

I would like to convert this into all parameter using htaccess
like: `domain?var1=p1&var2=p2&var3=p3&order=p4`

This is what I'm using right now:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/\order=[A-Za-z]?$ page.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&order=$4 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to match query parameter `?order=p4` here and you will need `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ page.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, probably i was looking in the wrong direction. Thanks a lot man.